# Rsync: use --files-from option with rsync NCBI daemon to download a large amount of files

Tags: linux, bash, ftp, rsync

I am trying to use rsync to download a large amount of files from ncbi.nlm.nih.gov, where the remote paths to the files are specified within a line separated file named "rsyncfilepaths". Previously with a smaller amount of files, I've simply put the file paths as arguments to rsync using `rsync $(tr '\n' ' ' < "rsyncfilepaths_small") /destination/path/`, but with a large amount of files in "filepaths" the number of arguments is so big that it causes an "Argument list too long" error. Here I believe the --files-from option could help, but I haven't gotten it to work.

The syntaxes I've tried using are variations of

`rsync -v --files-from=rsyncfilepaths rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov /desination/path/`

where I've tried combinations of having only the actual file names in "rsyncfilepaths", having the full path in "ryncfilepaths" (e.g. rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/path/to/file), and also excluding it (only /path/to/file) and also just the filename. I've also tried `rsync v --files-from=rsyncfilepaths / /destination/path/`. Using the first mentioned --files-from syntax I receive no error messages, but no files are downloaded, so there is obviously something wrong! Maybe there are some rsync experts out there who could help a beginner. Please ask for clarifications if something is unclear.

Edit:

Sample line in the "rsyncfilepaths" file:

`rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/128/725/GCA_900128725.1_BCifornacula_v1.0/GCA_900128725.1_BCifornacula_v1.0_genomic.fna.gz`

where the `rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA` part is the same for all lines.

Comment: Are the file-names and paths you want secret, or can you share some examples?

Comment: I could share a sample line:
```rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/128/725/GCA_900128725.1_BCifornacula_v1.0/GCA_900128725.1_BCifornacula_v1.0_genomic.fna.gz```.

Comment: This could probably be done with a combination of directory names and  (quoted) wildcards.  However, the `--files-from` option should also work.  I suspect your file contains control characters, like `CR LF` instead of just `LF`.

Comment: @user10489 Would the -s flag take care of the potential control character issue? I tried using it and there was no difference. I also tried using --files-from on a smaller subset (where it's easy to see that no special characters other than the sample I provided were used) but still no files were transferred.

Comment: I don't think `-s` has anything to do with this and would not help.  If your input file is in the wrong format, you just have to fix it.  The `-s` option tells rsync to *not* fix spaces anyway, so this is the opposite of what you need, even if it did do something related.

Comment: How would I know if the file is in the wrong format, or which characters that are disallowed? Is this rsync-daemon specific or general?

Comment: This seems to be a good answer, for both detection and fixing: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/121392/how-to-determine-the-line-ending-of-a-file

Comment: it works when i try.

Comment: `rsync -v  --files-from=list  rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/genomes/all/GCA/900/128/725/GCA_900128725.1_BCifornacula_v1.0 /tmp/`

Comment: @Jasen, the problem there is that the second argument to "--files-from" (where you put the rsync path) can't be a list of paths it seems like. Since each file I want to download has a different path this would have to be put inside a loop where the second argument is updated each time, unless I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: Aha! I misread your comment. :(

Comment: "Government-authorized use only" on the rsync://ftp.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/ home page, I think I'll stop experimenting.